# Properly coding PHP to scan and create a JSON from the videos directory

Tags: php, json

Hello so I have no knowledge whatsoever in PHP, I found a code that can create a json playlist by scanning the directory for the files and creating the proper formatting, I was wondering if any one could properly insert the directory /videos into the code.  videos is the folder that contains the mp4 files and is in the root directory

The original code I found here http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Generate_a_JSON_list_based_on_files_in_a_directo-GDc

All I want is for the code below to scan the videos directory.

Thank you!

```
  #!/usr/bin/php
<?php

/*
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Array of allowed file types
 */
$types = Array ('jpeg', 'jpg', 'txt', 'pdf', 'js', 'mp4', 'mp3', 'ogg');

if (!isset($argv[1]))
    exit("Must specify a directory to scan\n");

if (!is_dir($argv[1]))
    exit($argv[1]."' is not a directory\n");

/*
 * @name getList
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array based on array of file extensions
 * @return Array $files
 */
function getList($dir, $types)
{
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
    {
        if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $types))
            $files[] = $file->__toString();
    }
    return $files;
}

/*
 * @name getDetails
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array with details of each file
 * @return Array $files
 */
function getDetails($types, $array)
{
    foreach($types as $type)
    {
        foreach($array as $file)
        {
            if (strcasecmp($type, array_pop(explode('.', $file))) == 0) {
                $files[$type][basename($file)];
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['source'] = $file;
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['size'] = filesize($file);
            }
        }
    }
    return array('files'=>$files);
}

if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {

    /*
     * @name json_encode
     * @param Mixed $val
     * @abstract Alternate emulated json_encode function
     * @return Object $res
     */
    function json_encode($val)
    {
        if (is_string($val)) return '"'.addslashes($val).'"';
        if (is_numeric($val)) return $val;
        if ($val === null) return 'null';
        if ($val === true) return 'true';
        if ($val === false) return 'false';

        $assoc = false;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            if ($k !== $i++){
                $assoc = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $res = array();
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            $v = json_encode($v);
            if ($assoc){
                $k = '"'.addslashes($k).'"';
                $v = $k.':'.$v;
            }
            $res[] = $v;
        }
        $res = implode(',', $res);
        return ($assoc)? '{'.$res.'}' : '['.$res.']';
    }
}

/* Run application */
exit(json_encode(getDetails($types, getList($argv[1], $types))));
```

Comment: Instead of `$argv[1]`, write your directory, like `"/videos"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script was written to be executed from the command line, so from the console, you would execute this statement from the directory containing this script

```
php example.php /videos
```

you will also need to change the filename extensions to the video formats for which you're looking.

```
$types = Array ('jpeg', 'jpg', 'txt', 'pdf', 'js', 'mp4', 'mp3', 'ogg');
```

this might become

```
$types = Array ('mkv','avi','mp4','mov');
```

---

`$argv[1]` represents the argument passed to the script, which is used as the directory path in this case. so if you would like to call this script from a web server, then set that value in the script if it's empty so that you can still have the flexibility to execute it from the command line.

so change this line

```
if (!isset($argv[1]))
    exit("Must specify a directory to scan\n");
```

to this:

```
if (!isset($argv[1]))
    $argv[1] = '/videos';
```